# How to work with unicode in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode, replace, unicode-string

I am trying to clean all of the HTML out of a string so the final output is a text file.  I have some some research on the various 'converters' and am starting to lean towards creating my own dictionary for the entities and symbols and running a replace on the string.  I am considering this because I want to automate the process and there is a lot of variability in the quality of the underlying html.  To begin comparing the speed of my solution and one of the alternatives for example pyparsing I decided to test replace of \xa0 using the string method replace.  I get a

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The actual line of code was

```
s=unicodestring.replace('\xa0','')
```

Anyway-I decided that I needed to preface it with an r so I ran this line of code:

```
s=unicodestring.replace(r'\xa0','')
```

It runs without error but I when I look at a slice of s I see that the \xaO is still there

Comment: Why would you prefix '\xa0' with an r? That makes it a raw string - that is, it literally contains backslash, x, a, 0. Without the r, it contained a single character with hex code a0, which I think is what you wanted.

Comment: Because I was trying to guess why I got the error and I know that sometimes to force the \ to be read you have to make it a string literal and also the \xa0 is what actually exists in my source. what is hex code a0?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

may be you should be doing

```
s=unicodestring.replace(u'\xa0',u'')
```

Comment: So how did you know to do this since I have not seen this in any example?  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
s=unicodestring.replace('\xa0','')
```

..is trying to create the unicode character `\xa0`, which is not valid in an ASCII sctring (the default string type in Python until version 3.x)

The reason `r'\xa0'` did not error is because in a raw string, escape sequences have no effect. Rather than trying to encode `\xa0` into the unicode character, it saw the string as a "literal backslash", "literal x" and so on..

The following are the same:

```
>>> r'\xa0'
'\\xa0'
>>> '\\xa0'
'\\xa0'
```

This is something resolved in Python v3, as the default string type is unicode, so you can just do..

```
>>> '\xa0'
'\xa0'
```

> I am trying to clean all of the HTML out of a string so the final output is a text file

I would strongly recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for this. Writing an HTML cleaning tool is difficult (given how horrible most HTML is), and BeautifulSoup does a great job at both parsing HTML, and dealing with Unicode..

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><h1>Hi</h1></body></html>")
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>
   Hi
  </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer.  I have used BS to extract data from tables and it is very useful.  However, it seems to me that to remove the html using BS I have to know what is present.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can remove HTML via countless ways, from the first table in a div, to by-class-or-id etc..

Comment: BeautifulSoup.prettyify() was just a life saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [codecs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) standard library, specifically the **encode** and **decode** methods provided in the Codec base class.

There's also a good article [here](http://boodebr.org/main/python/all-about-python-and-unicode) that puts it all together.

Comment: Thanks-great article you are right it does put a lot together.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this, it's better to use standard python features.

For example:

```
string = unicode('Hello, \xa0World', 'utf-8', 'replace')
```

or

```
string = unicode('Hello, \xa0World', 'utf-8', 'ignore')
```

where `replace` will replace `\xa0` to `\\xa0`.

But if `\xa0` is really not meaningful for you and you want to remove it then use `ignore`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note regarding HTML cleaning. It is very very hard, since

```
<
body
>
```

Is a valid way to write HTML. Just an fyi.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to unicode in this way:

```
print u'Hello, \xa0World'  # print Hello,  World
```